# What should my shoulders position be when doing ring support hold

Tags: bodyweight-exercises, form, rings

When performing ring support hold, should I concentrate on having my shoulder blades retracted/clenched, and my chest forward, or is it fine if my shoulders are protracted?

Comment: Keep the shoulders neutral and depressed as much as possible. Neither protract nor retract the scapula too much.

Comment: @BKE Why didn't you post your comment as an answer? The correct answer is just like you wrote.

Comment: @BKE please post your comment as an answer, so that i can accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Keep the shoulders neutral and depressed as much as possible. Neither protract nor retract the scapula too much.

The main purpose of the ring support hold is to develop strength and stability in the shoulders in a balanced way, to build the foundation for progressions on the rings (eg. dips, L-sit etc). For this reason it is best not to exaggerate neither protraction, nor retraction.